# UIViewController still alive when dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, xml, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem removing UIViewController from memory, when I dismiss it I think it is still alive in the memory because if I re-instantiate the same UIViewController it starts from the same state it was when dismissed. All arrays I use in that UIViewController are doubled and not cleared.

This is the code where I instantiate it:

```
if counter == arrSize{

        resetQuestions()

        let v = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testViewController") as! PopupViewController
        v.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        v.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        v.setUserAnswers(answers: userAnswers)
        v.setCorrectAnswers(answers: correctAnsewrs)
        v.setQuestions(questions: questions)
        v.file = file
        v.setSelected(selected: selected)
        v.classObject = self

        self.present(v, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }
```

And this is the code where I dismiss it:

```
@IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
        self.removeFromParentViewController()
    })
}
```

I have also tried this code, but not working:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.viewDidDisappear(true)
    self.removeFromParentViewController()
}
```

Comment: @IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
} ,  this part should be enough

Comment: Try using `Debug Memory Graph` in Xcode. See if there a retain cycle occurring where this ViewController has a strong reference to another object, and that object also has a strong reference pointing back to your ViewController. For example, a delegate that is not marked `weak`.

Comment: Your arrays are doubled?  Are they static?  Or are you making new arrays in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @HaiR I don't create new arrays in viewDidLoad(), I set them before presenting the UIViewController `v.setUserAnswers(answers: userAnswers), v.setCorrectAnswers(answers: correctAnsewrs), v.setQuestions(questions: questions)`. If an array has 10 values, when I present the same UIViewController for the second time the array count goes 20 even if I dismiss that UIViewController before.